# Install program with Perl?

Tags: linux, debian, command-line, software-installation, perl

I'm trying to install GTK YouTube Viewer from GitHub (https://github.com/trizen/youtube-viewer) in Q4OS (Debian-based).

I downloaded the .zip file and extracted it, then tried to run the first command within the new directory:

```
perl Build.PL --gtk
```

Immediately, I'm met with the following error:

```
Can't locate Module/Build.pm in @INC (you may need to install the 
Module::Build module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-
gnu/perl/5.22.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-
gnu/perl5/5.22 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22 /usr/share
/perl/5.22 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base .) at 
Build.PL line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Build.PL line 7.
```

Am I missing dependencies, or is this a program error?

Comment: You'll need to install `Module::Build` and to perhaps encourage that code to not use that module: http://cpanratings.perl.org/dist/Module-Build#13150

Answer (score 4):

As said elsewhere, you'll need `Module::Build`:

```
apt-get install libmodule-build-perl
```

You should then be able to run Build.PL, make and install:

```
perl Build.PL --gtk && ./Build && ./Build install
```

You may run into trouble with further dependencies being required; installing modules via `apt-get` is fairly straightforward though.

Comment: Using the information you listed, I was able to get the installation working properly. Thanks for the help!